# how to make a group of Objects

Tags: groups

I have this problem.. i want to combine the objects into a group so that it becomes one object and when i move it (the group of objects), it moves as a single object/model. I know that we need to press ctrl + J to join the objects but this is not i want to do. I want to keep the materials separate. when i press ctrl + J everything becomes one and shares one material.

It might be a very basic thing for some but for me, i have never needed to do it before. so.. kindly guide!

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.79b or Blender 2.8 (or another version)?

Comment: Both.. It didn't work this way in 2.8 but it did in 2.79..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/relations/parents.html) objects:

1. In 3D view, select the objects you want to group. The first objects will be "children" and the last object will be "parent" (the active one).
2. So in 3D view header go to Object > Parent > Object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) to unite them.
3. Done! (just move the parent)

Note that:

a. Child objects will be sub items of the parent in Outliner.

b. You can move/rotate/scale the children independently, but when you do the same with the parent, all children will follow along.

c. To view links in the viewport, enable ~ Relationship Lines ~ in Overlays (2.8).

Comment: So the materials will remain separate?

Comment: Ok it works. Thanks a lot